# Trying to run a Task in .net 4.0 (using SSIS)

Tags: c#, .net, ssis, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I've got an SSIS package which contains a few scripts. One of them gets a token via a rest api.

I wrote the below, which works fine in .net 4.5 - however, our server isn't that up to date and we've got to downgrade to .net 4.0, which is where our hiccups begin as 4.0 has no GetAwaiter (and various other handy functions).

To add to the fun, as mentioned this is SSIS, where I believe you cannot add NuGet packages.

```
    public void Main()
    {
        //read the token from the file
        string ref_token = File.ReadAllText(Dts.Variables["User::PATH_refresh_token"].Value.ToString());
        **Dts.Variables["User::API_returned"].Value = GetToken(Dts.Variables["$Package::API_token_client_id"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["$Package::API_token_client_secret"].Value.ToString(), ref_token, Dts.Variables["$Package::API_token_endpoint"].Value.ToString()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();**
    }

    static async Task<string> GetToken(string client_id, string client_secret, string ref_token, string token_url)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", client_id),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", client_secret),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "refresh_token"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("refresh_token", ref_token),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("expiration", "20160")
            });
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            **var response = await client.PostAsync(token_url, content);**
            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return responseString;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.ToString();
        }
    }
```

So we're currently having issues with the GetAwaiter() (the fifth line in the code, highlighted):

> 'Task(string)' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'...

And also with the await in this line (also highlighted):

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(token_url, content);
```

> 'Task(HttpResponseMessage)' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter'...

Comment: `Task<TResult>.GetAwaiter()` was not introduced until .NET 4.5.

Comment: @JohnWu Yep, I know that now. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with .net 4.0 and need to find either a solution or some alternative code that works (at the moment I'm going for the latter).

Comment: You could use `Task<TResult>.Result`. The exception handling is slightly different but other than that it does the same thing as what you are doing.

Comment: @JohnWu Thanks for your help. Unfortunately the party I'm trying to connect to uses TLS12 and TLS11, which aren't supported in .net 4.0. Until we upgrade, I'll do this on my local machine using .net 4.5.

Comment: Do you really want to use Async calls in SSIS? SSIS core classes were created before TAP (await-async approach) advance, and do not support it. You need to wrap all your async calls in sync methods, keeping in mind all problems of such approach. Or - use sync counterparts. If you still opt for async - check `Task.Run(()=>{...})`, it is available in .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately the party I'm trying to connect to uses TLS12 and TLS11, which aren't supported in .net 4.0.

Well, then fixing the `GetAwaiter` issue isn't going to help.

But for posterity:

Any code using `await` can be transformed to equivalent code not using `await`. To do this, you'd need to split up your code by hand and use `ContinueWith` instead of `await` and `TaskCompletionSource<T>` instead of `async`. This is roughly [what the compiler is doing to your code](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/05/08/eduasync-part-1-introduction/) anyway.

Step by step:

First, you need to replace `async` with `TaskCompletionSource<T>`:

```
static Task<string> GetToken(...)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  try
  {
    ...
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    var response = await client.PostAsync(token_url, content);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return responseString;
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    return exception.ToString();
  }
}
```

All `return` statements now become code that sets the result of the TCS:

```
static Task<string> GetToken(...)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  try
  {
    ...
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    var response = await client.PostAsync(token_url, content);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    tcs.TrySetResult(responseString);
  }
  catch (Exception exception)
  {
    tcs.TrySetResult(exception.ToString());
  }
}
```

Next, remove the `try`/`catch` (but remember it's there). With `ContinueWith` we'll need to handle errors within the continuations:

```
static Task<string> GetToken(...)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  ...
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
  var response = await client.PostAsync(token_url, content);
  var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  tcs.TrySetResult(responseString);
//  catch (Exception exception)
//  {
//    tcs.TrySetResult(exception.ToString());
//  }
}
```

Now you can start converting the `await` statements to `ContinueWith`. For each one, move the rest of the method into a continuation. Note that [`ContinueWith` is dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html), so be sure to pass the correct scheduler. This code does not look like it needs the original context, so I'm using `TaskScheduler.Default`. So technically, this is a translation of `await` with `ConfigureAwait(false)` and not just a plain `await`, which would be more complex.

The continuation gets a task, which it can query for exceptions or results. Be aware of which members wrap exceptions in `AggregateException`; that can change your exception handling code.

This is what the first `await` transformation looks like:

```
static Task<string> GetToken(...)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  ...
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
  client.PostAsync(token_url, content).ContinueWith(task =>
  {
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
      tcs.TrySetResult(task.Exception.InnerException.ToString());
      return;
    }

    var response = task.Result;
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    tcs.TrySetResult(responseString);
  }, TaskScheduler.Default);
//  catch (Exception exception)
//  {
//    tcs.TrySetResult(exception.ToString());
//  }
}
```

The second `await` transformation can be done in a similar way:

```
static Task<string> GetToken(...)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  ...
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
  client.PostAsync(token_url, content).ContinueWith(task =>
  {
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
      tcs.TrySetResult(task.Exception.InnerException.ToString());
      return;
    }

    var response = task.Result;
    response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(task2 =>
    {
      if (task2.IsFaulted)
      {
        tcs.TrySetResult(task2.Exception.InnerException.ToString());
        return;
      }

      var responseString = task2.Result;
      tcs.TrySetResult(responseString);
    }, TaskScheduler.Default);
  }, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Alternatively, with simple `await` statements one after another, you can "chain" the continuations. You do need to use `Unwrap` since the first continuation returns a task. This approach looks like this:

```
static Task<string> GetToken(...)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  ...
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
  client.PostAsync(token_url, content).ContinueWith(task =>
  {
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
      tcs.TrySetResult(task.Exception.InnerException.ToString());
      return;
    }

    var response = task.Result;
    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  }, TaskScheduler.Default)
  .Unwrap()
  .ContinueWith(task =>
  {
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
      tcs.TrySetResult(task.Exception.InnerException.ToString());
      return;
    }

    var responseString = task.Result;
    tcs.TrySetResult(responseString);
  }, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

As a final note, with "chained" continuations, many people prefer to flow the exceptions through and flatten them at the end; the code is a little shorter that way:

```
static Task<string> GetToken(...)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  ...
  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
  client.PostAsync(token_url, content).ContinueWith(task =>
  {
    var response = task.Result;
    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
  }, TaskScheduler.Default)
  .Unwrap()
  .ContinueWith(task =>
  {
    if (task.IsFaulted)
    {
      tcs.TrySetResult(task.Exception.Flatten().InnerException.ToString());
      return;
    }

    var responseString = task.Result;
    tcs.TrySetResult(responseString);
  }, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

And that's why developers like the `async` and `await` keywords. ;)